# Select only one checkbox in a group but have option to select more than one if it's certain checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="6">
```

for example, i would like this group to have only one option but i would also like the user to be able to select  value 4 and 5 at the same time.

Is there a way to do this  without complex logic?

here is my script

```
$(function () {

    $('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {

        var checkboxArray = $('input:checkbox'); // CheckBoxList Items

        var current = $(this); // Get Selected Chec kbox 

        // Uncheck every checkBox that don't match the unique multi selection combo

        if (current.val() != "4" && current.val() != "5") {

            // Loop through checkboxArray and uncheck every item that does not meet the condition
            $(checkboxArray).each(function (i) {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            });

            // Check the selected item again
            $(current).prop("checked", true);
        } else {

            // Get the current checkbox value 
            var chk = $(current).val();

            // If the checkbox that matches the unique combo selection was click uncheck all invalid checkboxes that don't match
            if (chk == "4" || chk == "5") {

                // loop through the checkboxlist again
                $(checkboxArray).each(function () {
                    // Get the looped item name
                    var ck = $(this).val().text();
                    // if checkbox does not belong to the unique combo selection, uncheck it
                    if (ck != "4" && ck != "5") {
                        $(this).prop("checked", false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The user should be able to select only one but also be able to select more than one?

Comment: there are combo options, that's what i wanted to mean, you have a checklist, you will have certain options can be checked together, while the rest can only be checked alone

Comment: I posted a script  i tried before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var aCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='checkboxes[]']");

var aGroups = [
  [1, 2, 3, 6],
  [4, 5]
];



for (var i = 0; i < aCheckboxes.length; i++) {
  aCheckboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    checkGroups(e.target.value); //...call checkGroups...
  });
}

function enableCheckboxes() {
  for (var i = 0; i < aCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    aCheckboxes[i].disabled = false;
  }
}

function checkGroups(sCheckboxVal) {
  var isOneChecked = false;

  for (var x = 0; x < aCheckboxes.length; x++) { //Loop through all checkboxes
    if (aCheckboxes[x].checked === true) { //is checkbox is checked
      isOneChecked = true;
    }
  }
  enableCheckboxes(); //Enable all checkboxes

  if (isOneChecked === true) { //Is at least one checkbox is checked check groups
    aGroups.forEach(function(aGroup) { //Loop throgh your groups
      if (aGroup.indexOf(parseInt(sCheckboxVal)) === -1) { //Is checkbox not in group...
        for (x = 0; x < aGroup.length; x++) { //...loop thorugh all checkboxes...
          document.querySelectorAll("input[value='" + aGroup[x] + "']")[0].disabled = true; //...and disable checkbox
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="6">
```

Comment: This is probably a start for what i really have to do, i didn't think of splitting the check list into 2 groups before and this might be the best maintainable approach. Also there is a bug in this code. The 2nd group is enabled when you disable an option from the first group while having options checked on it. Either way, i will use this as a start